# Can I apply for a UK visa just to visit the Estonian Embassy in London?

Tags: united-kingdom, schengen, estonia

I just got hired in a company in Estonia as a web developer. I am Nigerian and there's no Estonian Representation here in Nigeria for long stay Visas.

I apparently just got back from Estonia o Tuesday(06/08/19) from a visit to the company for the final job interview. I applied through the Belgium embassy in Nigeria on the basis of a Job interview and was given a schengen Visa for 10 days(multiple entry). I got the Job offer and the visa expires by the end of August.

The mobility agent the company assigned to me suggested that I should apply for short stay Visas in either of the following embassies in Nigeria: UK, Cairo, India or Isreal. There are Estonian representations in these countries where I could then apply for long stay Visa.

There are a couple of challenges listed below: 
1. Cairo often makes it difficult for Nigerians. They could hold one's passport for months and return it without a visa. It's therefore not an option for me. 
2. Isreal only gives out visa to tour groups in Nigeria. It costs a fortune here to join a tour group. Pretty expensive. It's therefore not an option. 
3. India too makes it terribly tough for Nigerians. It's a no go area.

This leaves me with UK. I've been to the UK as a minor twice(2005 and 2008). The UK transit visa is only valid for 48hrs and is therefore not an option since it'll take the Estonian embassy 2 - 4 days to process the long stay visa.

My best option now is to apply for UK short stay visa. But how do I explain that I'm coming to the UK to just apply for a long term visa for Estonia and then head from the Uk to Estonia right away

Will the UK find my reason for applying credible and give me a visa?

Or could there be any other way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 2):

A UK residence permit is required to apply in the UK for a visa for Estonia https://london.mfa.ee/how-to-apply-for-a-schengen-visa/ so that avenue is not going to work for you.

According to https://workinestonia.com/internationalhouse/how-to-get-documents/ it looks possible to apply for a residence permit after returning to Estonia on a C type visa, which you could once again obtain via the Belgian Embassy in Nigeria. So I suggest you go back to your mobility agent and ask them to check the process, or contact an organisation such as ‘Work in Estonia’ who may be better informed than your agent.